# File does exists when calling .exists() but can't find it later

Tags: android, file, bitmap, directory, bitmapfactory

I'm trying to create a file that is eventually going to hold a picture (EXTRA_OUTPUT) like this:

```
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                      Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "scouthouse");
            if(!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
                mediaStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyyhhmmss");
            String format = s.format(new Date());
            File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + format + ".jpg");
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The mediaStorageDir.exists() returns true, but I can't find the folder in windows. The location is sdcard0/Pictures/scouthouse/. I do have a Pictures/ folder but Android doesn't create the /scouthouse/ folder.
When I try to decode the file with a Bitmapfactory it returns null.

EDIT!

So I've simplified the method a bit to get down to the root and basically have this:

```
   private void createDir() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "scouthouse");
    if(!file.mkdirs()) {
        Log.d("file", "file not created");
    }   
}
```

This creates a file dir, and the Log isn't logged for the first time. So the directory has been created, however
I can't find it on the phones file system anywhere.

```
    private File createNewFile() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "scouthouse" + File.separator + "test.jpg");
    try {
        if(file.createNewFile()) {
            Log.d("file", "yiss");
            return file;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

This method returns null. The file can't be created..

Comment: may be that file in the hidden mode try to rename it to other name..

Comment: alright tried a different static name 'test.jpg'. I can now conclude the file is not being created..

Comment: the .createNewFile() method returns false, but I can't seem to get why..

Comment: do you have write permissions in your manifest?

Comment: Yes. I have read and write permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The mediaStorageDir.exists() returns true, but I can't find the folder in windows.

Probably that is because `MediaStore` does not know about the directory, and so the MTP connection to Windows does not know about the directory. You can try using `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to resolve this, though I have only tried that for files, not directories. Also, even after indexing, you may need to do "Refresh" from your Explorer window, or disconnect/reconnect the device, as Windows may cache the MTP results and not detect a change even if Android knows about it.

Comment: I've reconnected the device and the directory doesn't display. How do I get the MediaStore to know about the directory?

Comment: @TimKranen: As I indicated in my answer, you can try using `MediaScannerConnection` and `scanFile()` to resolve this, though I have only tried that for files, not directories.

Comment: I've just checked the device itself, and you were right the directory is being created on the device but it isn't shown in Windows. Now the files are also created apparently but I can't open them. Still, the .createNewFile() call returns false..

Comment: @TimKranen: If the "files are also created apparently", then `createNewFile()` is supposed to return `false`.

Comment: public boolean createNewFile() -> This method returns true if it creates a file, false if the file already existed.

Comment: @TimKranen: Correct. And so if the "files are also created apparently", then the file will exist, and `createNewFile()` will return `false`. Use DDMS' File Manager, not Windows, to determine file existence until you get your `MediaScannerConnection` stuff worked out.

Comment: Ow, I'm sorry I forgot to mention that I'm using unique file names again.

Comment: @TimKranen: Then, since I don't know what code you are using, I cannot really help you further.

Comment: I think I get it now, I thought I used unique names but didn't. Thanks a lot for the help!