# Why files created with Java FileOutputStream on Android are visible on my pc throught USB after few ubs reconnectonions (+up to few minutes)

Tags: java, android, file

I have code like this:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), fileName);
FileOutputStream os = null;
try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(file);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("Error while creating FileOutputStream");
e.printStackTrace();
}
os.write("something".getBytes());
os.close();
```

and when i create file on my HTC desire x i have to disconnect usb, wait few minutes, connect it again to see created files in windows explorer. Why it's like that? And how can i prevent it?

And additionaly: when i use ls in terminal on my phone i see this file immediately.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File does exists when calling .exists() but can't find it later](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593334/file-does-exists-when-calling-exists-but-cant-find-it-later)

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `close()` on the FileOutputStream.

Comment: Ow, i forgot to copy it, but I have close().

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18593334/file-does-exists-when-calling-exists-but-cant-find-it-later and actually this is the solution. Now I'm trying to use it.